# How do I create a class for my player script in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{


    public float speed = 80.0f; // Code for how fast the ball can move. Also it will be public so we can change it inside of Unity itself. 
    private Rigidbody rb; // Variable that applies itself to Ball 


    // Code That enables our Player to move around. 
    void Movement()
    {

        float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal");
        float moveVertical = Input.GetAxis ("Vertical");
        Vector3 movement = new Vector3 (moveHorizontal, 0.0f, moveVertical);
        rb.AddForce (movement * speed);
    }


    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update ()
        {
            rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody> ();
            Movement ();
        }

}
```

Comment: This the code i have so far, I am just confused on how to create a class for it and create two instances of it. can someone lend me a hand

Comment: You have a class there : `public class PlayerController` it is called `PlayerController` You can attach this to GameObjects and each game object will then have it's own instance of this class.

Comment: You can then access it using : `yourGameObject.GetComponent<PlayerController>();`

Comment: Alright but what about making two players in my game? i'm so of confused on how to give each player a playerID attribute and make them behave differently based on what id i give them

Comment: You can create a prefab for your player object, it will contain it's own PlayerController component. You can then use code to load as many players as you want from the prefab

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Just like JanR said. Create another class called MainClass then from that class instantiate PlayerController as prefabs. You can load as many PlayerController  as possible if you make it a prefab.

Comment: I'm trying to define a class for the code above and apply it to two players objects and then include  a playerID attribute in my class and then finally ,make the players behave differently based on their ID.

Comment: i want to be able to apply the code above to two player objects but have each move based on input and have that be their attributes

Answer (score 1):

Your code above already is a `class` called `PlayerController`

In unity3d, you can drag the class onto your player `GameObject`. This will add the script as a component to your player object. When the player object is created it will create an instance of `PlayerController` for that object.

If you want to set the ID for a player:
Add a `playerId` property to your `PlayerController` class. Then when you spawn the player you can set the ID by accessing it's `PlayerController` by using `GetComponent<PlayerController>()` You can set the ID either in the script that is spawning the player, or you could use some code to do this in `void Start() {}`

Comment: Alright but what about making two players in my game? i'm so of confused on how to give each player a playerID attribute and make them behave differently based on what id i give them